# Visual studio 2017 c# BLL& DAL

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados, imagem

Tenho um problema de como guardar e tirar uma imagem da base de dados.
Gostaria de saber uma maneira de introduzir a imagem na base de dados tendo em conta que o numero de contribuinte é a chave primaria e que depois numa outra form possa usar codigo para ir busca-la há datagridview e por as informaçoes numa picturebox

```
public class BLL {
    public class Imagem {
        static public object loadpic(int Numero_de_contribuinte) {
            DAL dal = new DAL();
            SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] {
                new SqlParameter("@Numero_de_contribuinte", Numero_de_contribuinte),
            };
            return dal.executarScalar("select Imagem from Imagem where @Numero_de_contribuinte=@Numero_de_contribuinte", sqlParams);

        }
        static public DataTable Load() {
            DAL dal = new DAL();
            return dal.executarReader("select * from Imagem", null);
        }
        //Insere a imagem relativa ao numeroo de contribuinte
        static public int insertImagem(byte[] img, string Numero_de_contribuinte) {
            DAL dal = new DAL();
            SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] {
                new SqlParameter("@img", img),
                new SqlParameter("@Numero_de_contribuinte", Numero_de_contribuinte)

            };

            return dal.executarNonQuery("INSERT into Imagem (Imagem,Numero_de_contribuinte) VALUES(@img,@Numero_de_contribuinte)", sqlParams);
        }
    }   

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // Code Snippet
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        byte[] buff = ms.GetBuffer();
        int g = BLL.Imagem.insertImagem(buff, textBox2.Text);

        /*  OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
              open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
              if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              {
                  Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                  pictureBox1.Image = bit;
                  int a = BLL.Imagem.insertImagem(bit, textBox1.Text);


              }*/

    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int o = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);

        BLL.Imagem.loadpic(o);

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Pedro, não poste imagens do seu código, coloque o próprio texto do seu código na pergunta.

Comment: Sou novo nisto,para a proxima ja sei

Comment: Não precisa esperar a próxima é só clicar no link "editar" no final da pergunta e alterar :)

Comment: obrigado ja esta so vou por pelo menos a imagem do design para se ter uma ideia :)

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link para ter ideia de como fazer:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-save-images-in-mysql-database-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: vou dar uma vista de olhos

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: Eu gostaria de conseguir guardar a imagem na base de dados .
e depois conseguir ao clicar na datagridview demonstrar a imagem numa picturebox. até agora só consegui por os dados que levam letras e numeros a serem guardados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu sugeria uma abordagem fácil e rápida de se fazer que é guardares o **URL** da imagem na Base de Dados. Não precisas de guardar a imagem em si, só precisas de garantir que ela existe no caminho que puseste na BD. Depois do lado do C#, na PictureBox só precisas de colocar a URL no método [PictureBox.Load(string URL) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx).

A única coisa que precisas de ter atenção é se o local da imagem não for o mesmo. Então caminhos absolutos não iram funcionar. Tens que usar um caminho relativo.